# Powerapps: submit and then going to the last modified folders automatically but i want the current folder and not the last

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

i have a powerapps application, with two edit screen for one application.
So when the first edit_form is ok and submitted, i would like that the user go on the next `edit_form` of THE CURRENT FOLDER WITH SAME ID OF THE FIRST EDIT FORM.
But in fact, if I don't do some modifications on the edit form number 1 and i want to go on the second edit screen.

Here is the problem: The user go on the last folders which has been modified, so this is another folder with another ID !
[image]

Comment: How can i go on the same folder with the same ID on the second edit screen, if i don't do some modifications to the editscreen number 1. I want to have the same ID and the same folder...

Comment: This is my formula when you click on the button to switch on the next edit screen :
**SubmitForm(EditForm1);EditForm(EditForm1_1);Navigate(EditForm1_1)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have found a solution !**

In fact, i generate a random number in a variable with Set() and Rand()  :

```
Set(idcourant;BrowseGallery1_1.Selected.ID);;Set(baliseNumber;Rand());;Select(Parent)
```

Then:

```
Patch(QuickCheckEST;First(Filter(QuickCheckEST;ID = idcourant ));{balise:baliseNumber});;SubmitForm(EditForm1);;Navigate(EditForm1_1)
```

With this formulas, my record is always new and updated with a random number, so when i switch on the edit_screen and and the second edit screen , i can  stay on the same record/folder, because my record has been updated and recorded with the random number in the SharePoint List !